# How to Obtain the wsChromeEndpointUrl on windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, puppeteer

[To use puppeteer with existing chrome browser](https://medium.com/@jaredpotter1/connecting-puppeteer-to-existing-chrome-window-8a10828149e0), we need to launch chrome with argument `–remote-debugging-port=9222` and then read the printout like

```sh
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/41a0b5f0–6747–446a-91b6–5ba30c87e951
```

This URL, `ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/41a0b5f0–6747–446a-91b6–5ba30c87e951` is needed to connect peppeteer to chrome instance. And it changes everytime we launch the application. On macOS or Unix-based OS, this is not a problem.

However, when starting the chrome on windows there won't be its printout. These are the command line I use to start the chrome on Winodws

```
start chrome.exe –remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Or, in powershell

```
Start-Process "chrome.exe" -ArgumentList -remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Is there any way I can obtain such a URL on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version` And  You will see it under `webSocketDebuggerUrl`

```
{
   "Browser": "Chrome/75.0.3770.100",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "7.5.288.23",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@cd0b15c8b6a4e70c44e27f35c37a4029bad3e3b0)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/b0662788-1cfe-4ddb-9ed0-04c4ce95e1d2"
}
```

That is, in my case, `"ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/b0662788-1cfe-4ddb-9ed0-04c4ce95e1d2"`

Answer (score 1):

The `browserURL` option will do that job for you. You can do:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9222'});
```

And puppeteer will call the `json/version` endpoint for you.